# Вернуть дерево предков блока, на который был произведен клик

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Суть задачи в том, чтобы когда я нажимал на любой блок на странице сайта, мне выдавало полный путь от body до этого элемента. То бишь функция, которая возвращает дерево предков блока, на который нажали, вплоть до body, и в случае если таких элементов несколько, то возвращался еще и индекс блока, на который нажали. Пробовал через `parent()` и `parents()`, но до точки так и не дошел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Функция, которая возвращает селектор передаваемого аргументом тега
 */
const expose = tag => { 
  /* Селектор формируется именем тега плюс 
     если есть id, то #id,
     иначе прибавляем классы */ 
  let sel = `${tag.tagName.toLowerCase()}`+
           ( tag.id?`#${tag.id}`:
             tag.className?`.${tag.className.replace(/ /g,'.')}`:
             ''), col; 
  /* Если у элемента нет id, 
     и с таким селектором в родителе находит не один элемент,
     то можно прибавить к селектору индекс элемента */
  if(!tag.id&&(col=tag.parentNode.querySelectorAll(sel)).length>1)
    sel+=`:nth-child(${[...col].findIndex(el=>tag==el)+1})`; 
  /* возвращаем селектор */
  return sel;
}
/* событие onclick */  
document.body.onclick = e => 
  /* собираем общий селектор до тега, куда кликнули */
  alert(e.path.reverse().splice(3).map(expose).join('>'));

/* Дальнейший код к задаче не относится, но может помочь в отладке */
let selected; 
document.body.onmousemove = e => { 
  let { x, y } = e; 
  if(selected) selected.style.outline = '';
  selected = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
  if(selected) selected.style.outline='1px solid red';
};
```

Comment: Так как я почти ничего из этого не понял (будь прокляты стрелочные функции), то я решил просто впихнуть в мою структуру все это и понажимать на блоки. Результат - ничего не происходит

Comment: @AdamShadiev Странно, у меня все работает... Может быть, вы перегружаете событие или вовсе отменяете его где-нибудь.

Comment: Без каких либо правок, просто впихнуть это все в скрипты, и все работает? Классы у меня есть у всех элементов на странице, а вот с id и index по пальцам пересчитать, мб из-за этого не хочет робить?(

Comment: я впихиваю прямо на странице stackoverflow в DevTools в консоли

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Переменная для хранения крайнего полученного пути (дерева)
var t = null;

// Создаем событие для клика на странице
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    t = e.path; // Сам путь (готовое свойство события)
    console.log(t); // Выводим путь при клике
})
```

Вывод до body

```
// Переменная для хранения крайнего полученного пути (дерева)
var t = null;

// Создаем событие для клика на странице
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    t = e.path; // Сам путь (готовое свойство события)
    const index = t.findIndex(item => (item.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'body'))
    console.log(t.slice(0, index + 1)); // Выводим путь при клике до body
})
```

Comment: Ваше решение выводит в консоль весь путь блока, как я и хотел, вот только в случае когда блоки одинаковые, нам еще надо возвращать индекс этого блока (нажали на первый блок с таким путем, на второй и т.д.)

Comment: И есть ли возможность выводить до определенного элемента? (допустим выводить весь путь до body)

Comment: Вы можете поиском по массиву, либо по id, либо по имени тега, обрезать путь как вам нужно.

Comment: @AdamShadiev Добавил второй блок кода для вывода до body

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Теперь мне осталось с индексами разобраться